# Is this even a function in Haskell ? If so, how should we read it?

Tags: haskell, recursion, primes, lazy-evaluation

In the book of *The Haskell Road to Logic, Math and Programming* by Doets et.al., at page 103, it is given that

```
prime :: Integer -> Bool
prime n | n < 1     = error "not a positive integer"
        | n == 1    = False
        | otherwise = ldp n == n where 
  ldp    = ldpf primes
  ldpf (p:ps) m | rem m p == 0 = p
                | p^2 > m = m
                | otherwise = ldpf ps m 
  primes = 2 : filter prime [3..]
```

However, isn't the logic of this function circular ? I mean I think I'm quite comfortable with recursive functions, but I do not think that this is a recursive function. Even if it is, I'm not able to comprehend the logic of it, so my question is that how to read the logic of such a function.

**Edit:**

The reason why I'm confused is `prime` function uses the list `primes`, but to generate that list, we also use the function `prime`, so it seems that there is a circular logic, or I just do not understand recursive functions with lazy evaluation.

Comment: Please post code as text rather than screenshots. It makes reading, local testing, and searching far easier.

Comment: What part makes you think the logic is circular

Comment: @Carl See my edit.

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: Haskell is lazy; trace a call to `prime 2`, and notice how you never actually use `ps` in the call to `ldpf`. That means the recursive call to `prime` never actually gets made until you actually need it.

Comment: Haskell is magic like that. This is too complex a function to contemplate, try grokking this Fibonacci sequence implementation first: `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. Note that it produces an *infinite* list.

Answer (score 4):

The `ldp n == n` condition can be equivalently re-written as

```
ldpf primes n == n
=
null [() | p <- takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= n) primes, rem n p==0]
=
and [rem n p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= n) primes]
```

so for any given `n`, the call `prime n = ldp n == n` only needs to generate the list

```
primes = 2 : filter prime [3..] 
       = 2 : filter (\n -> ldpf primes n == n) [3..]
       = 2 : filter (\n -> and [rem n p > 0 
                                | p <- takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= n) primes])
                          [3..]
```

up to the smallest prime number `q > floor (sqrt $ fromIntegral n)`, and for that only the primes not greater than *`q`'s* square root are needed. And to generate those, only the numbers not greater than the square root of *that* were needed. Pretty soon we end up not needing any primes at all, e.g.

```
prime 3
= 
ldpf primes 3 == 3
=
and [rem 3 p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= 3) (2 : filter prime [3..])]
= 
and [rem 3 p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (<= 3) (4 : 
                                      map (\p -> p^2) (filter prime [3..]))]
= 
and [rem 3 p > 0 | p <- []]
=
and []
=
True
```

because `2` already fails the predicate: `(2^2 <= 3) = (4 <= 3) = False`.

And when testing `4`, `primes` will be probed for containing the number `3`, but that's OK as we've just seen above:

```
prime 4
=
and [rem 4 p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= 4) primes]
= 
and [rem 4 p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (<= 4) (4 : 
                               map (\p -> p^2) (filter prime [3..]))]
= 
and [rem 4 p > 0 | p <- 4 : takeWhile (<= 4) (9 :
                               map (\p -> p^2) (filter prime [4..]))]
= 
and [rem 4 p > 0 | p <- 4 : []]
=
False
```

and we can check it at the GHCi prompt after that,

```
> :sprint primes
2 : 3 : _
```

(for the above to work you'll need to take `primes` out of the `prime` function and make it a top-level entity in its own right).

Comment: cf. [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688063/haskell-to-fix-or-not-to-fix/21720650#21720650), and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894417/double-stream-feed-to-prevent-unneeded-memoization/13895347#13895347).