# How the channels work in this example?

Tags: go, primes, channel, sieve

This is is an example of prime number sieve

```
package main

func Generate(ch chan<- int) {
  for i := 2; ; i++ {
    ch <- i
  }
}

func Filter(in <-chan int, out chan<- int, prime int) {
  for {
    i := <-in
    if i%prime != 0 {
      out <- i
    }
  }
}

func main() {
  ch := make(chan int)
  go Generate(ch)
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    prime := <-ch
    print(prime, "\n")
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    go Filter(ch, ch1, prime)
    ch = ch1
  }
}
```

What I understand is this line of code

```
prime := <-ch
```

the channel is waiting for an input and assigns to prime. So, why all the numbers are not printed when the next statement is called

```
print(prime, "\n")
```

If I remove these last 3 lines

```
ch1 := make(chan int)
go Filter(ch, ch1, prime)
ch = ch1
```

then all numbers are printed from 2 to 11. What does this line do ch = ch1?

Thanks

Comment: Context: http://golang.org/doc/play/sieve.go. Also optimized in http://blog.onideas.ws/eratosthenes.go

Comment: @VonC thanks for the link. the article cited lacks the idea of [postponement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8871918/849891) - an intermediate yet significant improvement step. Another important optimization (related to postponement, really) is [reducing memory retention](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13895347/849891) by breaking open the feedback loop (that the blog mentions). This makes possible to have a tower of prime-producing channels, each with only a small buffer (python version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/849891) - see the 4th line in the code).

Comment: @WillNess looks good indeed at first glance.

Comment: here's [the working code on ideone](http://ideone.com/RPwHJe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code's  output is :

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

So  the procedure is like this :

i=0,

after `prime := <-ch` , prime=2, ch = {3};

after `go Filter(ch, ch1, prime)` , mark as `Filter0`,in function `Filter0` channel `in` will be 3,4,5,6 ... and channel `out` will be 3,5,7 ...;

After `ch = ch1`, So ch = {3}, which  will be 3,5,7.

i=1,

after `prime := <-ch` ,prime= 3, ch ={5},why is there `5` in `ch`?'Cause now `ch` is the `ch1` in last loop ;

after `go Filter(ch, ch1, prime)` ,  mark as `Filter1`,in function `Filter1` channel `in` will be 5,7,9,11 ... and channel `out` will be 5,7,11 ...;

After `ch = ch1`, So ch = {3}, which  will be 5,7,11.

i=2, the same .

That how it output.

Answer (score 1):

The reason not all numbers are printed is because it's not the same channel in each iteration of the loop. It creates a new channel ch1 and filters values from ch into ch1 and then it assigns ch to ch1 so that the next iteration ch is the new channel from the previous iteration (there known as ch1) and the values there have been filtered by the Filter goroutine.

Here is another way to write it that may make more sense to you:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    prime := <-ch
    print(prime, "\n")
    oldch := ch          //here oldch references the old channel
    ch = make(chan int)  //and here ch is replaced with a new channel
    go Filter(oldch, ch, prime) //and here a filter is applied to values from oldch to ch
}
```