# Checking Uniqueness of Shifting Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, performance, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My code is as follows:

```
int main(){
    vector<int> primes;
    vector<int> primesSum;
    int tally = 1;
    bool primeFound = false;
    while (true) {
        int i = 0;
        while (!primeFound) {
            primeFound = true;
            tally++;
            for (i = 0; i < (int)primes.size(); i++) {
                if (tally == primesSum[i]) {
                    primeFound = false;
                    primesSum[i] += primes[i];
                }
            }
        }
        primeFound = false;
        primesSum.push_back(tally*2);
        primes.push_back(tally);
    }
}
```

It seems to generate prime numbers fine but I was wondering if I could increase its efficiency by implementing the rule that all primes are 6n +/- 1 after 2 and 3. That would seem to sacrifice my achievement of initially empty vectors though.

I've seen prime number verifiers that make use of the 6n +/- i rule but not really in sieve programs, likely as it breaks the 2 filter.

Edit: as an aside I would prefer to not use modulo as that is another achievement for this program, unless a modulo is more efficient (time-wise not space-wise) than what I currently have.

Comment: Its common to combine [wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) with sieving (particularly the [sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)).

Comment: @DillonDavis Yes but I can't really figure out how to implement it without breaking it being infinitely repeatable and maintaining not knowing 2 and 3 are prime.

Comment: ot: `(int)primes.size()` you should not use a casts like this to silence a compiler warning. Why is `i` not unsigned?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thats less of me thinking it’s better in an efficiency sense and moreso a matter of preference. I can more easily grasp int at first glance than unsigned.

Comment: my point is that `(int)` as cast is a red flag. It will not pass a code review. Correctness is way more important than performance. The cast is ok here, but nevertheless it hides a compiler warning without actually fixing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that I wrote to efficiently generate primes using a sieve that only considers integers that are +-1 mod 6. It is written as a generator using a coroutine library, but the logic is equivalent. It uses a `vector` of `uint64_t`'s as a bit mask.

There are no modulo's related to computing the primes, but they are used to access the bitmap.

**Update**

I extracted my original code from the generator and created a simple function that puts the primes in a vector. One method uses the +-1 mod 2 search and the other +-1 mod 6 search. I also extracted the OP's code into a function.

I ran some simple timing measurements on an M1 Max (arm64).

| function | primes<1M | primes<10M | primes<100M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sieve_index | 12904 ms | still running... |  |
| sieve_2n | 2 ms | 30 ms | 222 ms |
| sieve_6n. | 1 ms | 15 ms | 132 ms |

The code and build instructions can be found at the GitHub repo [cpp-core/so](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git)

#### Code

```
auto sieve_mod6_prime_seq(int max = int{1} << 20) {
    std::vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);
    primes.push_back(3);

    auto max_index = max / 3;
    auto bits_per = sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT;
    auto nwords = (bits_per + max_index - 1) / bits_per;
    std::vector<uint64_t> words(nwords);

    words[0] |= 1;
    size_t wdx = 0;
    while (wdx < nwords) {
        auto b = std::countr_one(words[wdx]);
        auto p = 3 * (64 * wdx + b) + 1 + (b bitand 1);
        if (b < 64 and p < max) {
            primes.push_back(p);

            for (auto j = p; j < max; j += 6 * p) {
                auto idx = j / 3;
                auto jdx = idx / 64;
                auto jmask = uint64_t{1} << (idx % 64);
                words[jdx] |= jmask;
            }

            for (auto j = 5 * p; j < max; j += 6 * p) {
                auto idx = j / 3;
                auto jdx = idx / 64;
                auto jmask = uint64_t{1} << (idx % 64);
                words[jdx] |= jmask;
            }
        }
        else {
            ++wdx;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

auto sieve_mod2_prime_seq(int max = int{1} << 20) {
    std::vector<int> primes;

    auto bits_per = 2 * sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT;
    auto nwords = (bits_per + max - 1) / bits_per;
    std::vector<uint64_t> words(nwords);
    if (max > 2)
        primes.push_back(2);
    words[0] |= 1;
    size_t idx = 0;
    while (idx < nwords) {
        auto bdx = 2 * std::countr_one(words[idx]) + 1;
        auto p = 128 * idx + bdx;
        if (bdx < 128 and p < max) {
            primes.push_back(p);
            for (auto j = p; j < max; j += 2 * p) {
                auto jdx = j / 128;
                auto jmask = uint64_t{1} << ((j % 128) / 2);
                words[jdx] |= jmask;
            }
        }
        else {
            ++idx;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

auto sieve_index(int max = int{1} << 20) {
    std::vector<int> primes;
    std::vector<int> primesSum;
    int tally = 1;
    bool primeFound = false;
    while (tally < max) {
        int i = 0;
        while (!primeFound) {
            primeFound = true;
            tally++;
            for (i = 0; i < (int)primes.size(); i++) {
                if (tally == primesSum[i]) {
                    primeFound = false;
                    primesSum[i] += primes[i];
                }
            }
        }
        primeFound = false;
        primesSum.push_back(tally*2);
        primes.push_back(tally);
    }
    return primes;
}

template<class Work>
void measure(std::ostream& os, std::string_view desc, Work&& work) {
    chron::StopWatch timer;
    timer.mark();
    work();
    auto millis = timer.elapsed_duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>().count();
    os << fmt::format("{:>30s}: {} ms", desc, millis) << endl;
}

int tool_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ArgParse opts
        (
         argValue<'n'>("number", 1000, "Number of primes"),
         argFlag<'v'>("verbose", "Verbose diagnostics")
         );
    opts.parse(argc, argv);
    auto n = opts.get<'n'>();
    // auto verbose = opts.get<'v'>();

    measure(cout, "sieve_index", [&]() { sieve_index(n); });
    measure(cout, "sieve_2n", [&]() { sieve_mod2_prime_seq(n); });
    measure(cout, "sieve_6n", [&]() { sieve_mod6_prime_seq(n); });
    return 0;
}
```

**End Update**

You can easily adapt it to construct a `vector` of primes by replacing each `co_yield` with `vec.push_back`.

```
coro::Generator<uint64_t> sieve_mod6_prime_seq(uint64_t max = uint64_t{1} << 20) {
    co_yield 2;
    co_yield 3;

    auto max_index = max / 3;
    auto bits_per = sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT;
    auto nwords = (bits_per + max_index - 1) / bits_per;
    std::vector<uint64_t> words(nwords);

    words[0] |= 1;
    size_t wdx = 0;
    while (wdx < nwords) {
        auto b = std::countr_one(words[wdx]);
        auto p = 3 * (64 * wdx + b) + 1 + (b bitand 1);
        if (b < 64 and p < max) {
            co_yield p;

            for (auto j = p; j < max; j += 6 * p) {
                auto idx = j / 3;
                auto jdx = idx / 64;
                auto jmask = uint64_t{1} << (idx % 64);
                words[jdx] |= jmask;
            }

            for (auto j = 5 * p; j < max; j += 6 * p) {
                auto idx = j / 3;
                auto jdx = idx / 64;
                auto jmask = uint64_t{1} << (idx % 64);
                words[jdx] |= jmask;
            }
        }
        else {
            ++wdx;
        }
    }
    co_return;
}
```

Comment: That looks really nice and I'll have to give it a go later, but wouldn't the large amount of multiplication and division increase the time complexity?

Comment: On modern hardware, arithmetic is much cheaper than memory access making it worthwhile in this case. Also, the division and modulo by 64 are converted to simple shift and mask operations by the compiler. I believe the code is well optimized at least for arm64 -- I haven't tested it on x86.

Answer (score 0):

I must say, the naming of variables and the code structure as posted in the question, with the double `while` instead of an `if`, is very non-conducive to the code clarity.

Consequently, I'd re-structure your code as

```
int main(){
    vector<int> primes;   // primes known so far
    vector<int> mults;    // smallest multiple of each prime, above c
    int c = 1;            // candidates: 2,3,...
    bool composite;
    while (true) {
        composite = false;
        c++;              // 2,3,...
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)primes.size(); i++) {
            if (c == mults[i]) {  // if c is a multiple of ith prime,
                composite = true;   // then it's composite.
                mults[i] += primes[i]; // next multiple of this prime
            }
        }
        if( !composite ) {
            mults.push_back(c*2);   // first multiple of 
            primes.push_back(c);    //   newly found prime
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can see, first of all, a major *algorithmic* deficiency in your code: the wrong "data structure" you use to maintain the primes' multiples. Instead of min-heap priority queue which would immediately produce the next known multiple of a prime, you maintain two linear vectors and scan through them for each candidate number. This is bound to have major implications, complexity-wise. And with worse complexity no amount of constant factors improvements will help much.

But putting this aside, on to your question. You enumerate the multiples of each prime `p` as `2p, 3p, 4p, ...`.

First step is to switch it to `p², p²+p, p²+2p, ...`.

Next, we notice that for all odd primes, `p²` is odd as well and so the enumeration can be changed to `p², p²+2p, p²+4p, ...`, to enumerate all *odd* multiples of it.

And what to do with the *even* ones? How to test for them now? The whole point to this "wheel factorization" optimization is to *not* do any such tests, but just ignore them. That's why it's an optimization in the first place.

And the way to ignore them is to *not* generate any *even* candidates, in the first place -- because we known in advance that all of them aren't primes any way. And *that* is the essence of the wheel optimization:

```
int main(){
    vector<int> primes;   // primes known so far
    vector<int> mults;    // smallest multiple of each prime, above c
    int c = 1;            // candidates: 3,5,...
    bool composite;
    while (true) {
        composite = false;
        c+=2;             // 3,5,...
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)primes.size(); i++) {
            if (c == mults[i]) {  // if c is a multiple of ith prime,
                composite = true;   // then it's composite
                mults[i] += 2*primes[i]; // next multiple of this prime
            }
        }
        if( !composite ) {
            mults.push_back(c*c);   // first multiple of 
            primes.push_back(c);    //   newly found prime
        }
    }
}
```

Next, switching to your desired `mod 6 +-1` enumeration, we will ignore the multiples of 2 *and* 3. But then it means, we'll need to not generate any of them as well. The enumeration of multiples will be `m=p²; m+=4; m+=2; m+=4; m+=2; m+=4; m+=2; ...` for some, and `m=p²; m+=2; m+=4; m+=2; m+=4; m+=2; m+=4; ...` for others (you can figure out the details).

And the enumeration of the candidates will just start from 5, and also proceed as `c=5; c+=2; c+=4; c+=2; c+=4; c+=2; c+=4; ...`.

Hopefully you can write this down now in an actual code.

P.S. you can find more details in several of my answers on the matter, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=sieve%20wheel%20user%3a849891&searchOn=3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69336435/849891) etc..